# What is the period and phase shift of $f(x)=3\sin 4\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-1$?

Tags: calculus

For the function what is the period and the phase shift respectively are:?

$$f(x) = 3\sin 4\left(x +\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - 1$$

**My attempt:** It is wrong though.

$y = a\sin b(x\pm h) \pm k$

$a$ : amplitude $\implies$ take absolute value

$b$ : angular frequency

$h$ : horizontal shift (phase shift). ($+$ left, $-$ right)

$k$ : mid. line or vertical shift ($+$ up, $-$ down)

period = $\dfrac{2\pi}{b}$ ( for sines, cosines; if tangent $p = \dfrac{\pi}{b}$)

---

$f(x) = 3\sin 4\left(x + \dfrac{π}{4}\right) - 1$

$b = 4$

period = $\dfrac{2\pi}{4} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

phase shift: left $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: I think I have a negative sign missing ? any input or something

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say that your attempt is wrong. That's how I learned it.

---

**Edit**: As you've mentioned in the comments below, the options provided to you are

> (A) period $4$ and phase shift $-\cfrac\pi4$
>
> (B) period $\cfrac\pi2$ and phase shift $-\cfrac\pi4$
>
> (C) period $-\cfrac\pi2$ and phase shift $-\cfrac\pi4$
>
> (D) period $-\cfrac\pi2$ and phase shift $\cfrac\pi4$

Using the method that you were given to find the period, the only possible option is (B). Remember that a phase shift of $-\cfrac\pi4$ is the same thing as a phase shift of $\cfrac\pi4$ to the left, so this is the same as your answer.

---

**Edit**: Let me give you some alternate (hopefully clearer) rules. Suppose you are given an equation $$y=a\sin\bigl(b(x-h)\bigr)+k$$ or $$y=a\cos\bigl(b(x-h)\bigr)+k$$ for some real $a,b,h,k$ where $a\ne0$ and $b>0$. (If $a=0$ or $b=0,$ there's really nothing interesting to say. Do you know why we may assume that $b$ isn't negative?) Then:

> The amplitude is $|a|$. Graphically, this will be the vertical distance from the max (or min) value to the midline, or half the vertical distance from the max value to the min value.
>
> The phase shift is $h$. Graphically, this is a shift by $|h|$ to the right if $h$ is positive; by $|h|$ to the left if $h$ is negative.
>
> The midline shift is $k$. Graphically, this is a shift by $|k|$ upward if $k$ is positive; by $|k|$ downward if $k$ is negative.

Comment: Well on the worksheet these are the answers

Comment: A. period:4 and phase shift: -pi/4 B.period pi/2 and phase shift -pi/4 C. period -pi/2 and phase shift -pi/4 D. period -pi/2 and phase shift pi/4

Comment: So I did something wrong :(

Comment: One of those matches your attempt. You did nothing wrong. You just need to pick the correct option.

Comment: which one haha! I don't see it lol

Comment: Only one has a period that matches yours. The "$-$" in a phase shift means left (as you, yourself noted).

Comment: @user73122: Are you still unsure about my answer?