# What is an equation for cosine function graphed below?

Tags: calculus

[image]

my answer ? Please correct me if am wrong and explain your reasoning

$y\,\,\, = \,\,\,5\cos {3 \over 2}\left( {x\,\, + \,\,{\pi  \over 3}} \right)\,\, - \,\,2$

Comment: Using the rules from [your previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/406293/28900), the graph from your equation will have midline $-2$ (as this does), amplitude $5$ (as this does), phase shift $\frac\pi3$ to the left (as this does), and period $\frac{4\pi}3$ (as this does). Good work.

Answer (score 1):

You've done it fine... [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5cos%281.5%28x%2B%28pi%2F3%29%29%29-2) says it's right. Shifting rules for graphs is generally employed in such cases. Let $y=f(x)$, then $(y-a)=f(x-b)$ displaces the graph of $y=f(x)$ $a$ units up and $b$ units to the right.

Comment: how did you do it on wolfram

Comment: Entered your formula just.

Comment: @user73122:  The word Wolfram in the answer is a link that shows how it was done.